# UITextView mark text

Tags: objective-c, swift, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` and would like to offer the user a chance to mark text within this text view.

I have tried to use `UITextPosition` but it is not precise enough and I do not know which text has being marked.

```
UITextPosition *tapPos = [textView closestPositionToPoint:touchPosition];

UITextRange *wr = [textView.tokenizer rangeEnclosingPosition:touchPosition withGranularity:UITextGranularityWord inDirection:UITextLayoutDirectionRight];
```

This solution also does not solve the next step of dragging along the words in order to mark more than one word.

I thought of something like the makers of Lightly did.
http://lightlyapp.com

Comment: Take a look at TTTAttributedLabel - it should be able to do what you want.